# AMM, proposed by Richard L. Bishop and Lee A. Rubel Prove that the differential equation $z^4\frac{d^2W}{dz^2}=W^4$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Prove that the differential equation$$z^4\frac{d^2W}{dz^2}=W^4$$has no nonconstant entire solutions, but that, for every $R>0$, it does have a non-constant solution analytic in $\{z:|z|<R\}$.

Let $W=\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n z^n$. The equation turns into a recursion on the coefficients: $a_1$ is arbitrary, and for $n\geq 2$:
$a_n=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum_{i+j+k+l=n+2}a_ia_ja_ka_l$I claim that for any $c>0$, we can choose $a_1>0$ so that $a_n\leq \frac{1}{n}c^{3n-2}$ for all $n$. Indeed, we can obviously guarantee the inequality holds for all $n\leq 10^{100}$. Then, for $n>10^{100}$, write by induction
$a_n\leq \frac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum_{i+j+k+l=n+2}\frac{1}{ijkl}c^{3n-2}$ so that it is enough for $\sum \frac{1}{ijkl}\leq n-1$. This however is proven by
$\sum_{i+j+k+l=n+2}\frac{1}{ijkl}\leq \sum_{i, j, k, l\leq n}\frac{1}{ijkl}=H_n^4\leq 16(\log n)^4<n-1$ where the last equation holds for all $n\geq 10^{100}$ (replace it with a larger number if necessary).

The resulting series for $W$ will converge for all $|z|<\frac{1}{c}$.

I don't know how to prove no entire solution exists yet

Comment: Is this it? Bishop, Richard L.; Rubel, Lee A.; Israel, Robert B.; Lossers, O. P.
Problems and Solutions: Solutions: 6651.
Amer. Math. Monthly 99(1992), no.10, 961–963.

Comment: Yesssssssssssss

Comment: So, tell us why you did not like the published solution...

Comment: I came across this question on the internet as per the source the question Is AMM, proposed by Richard L. Bishop and Lee A. Rubel  but I'm unable to find an official solution.

Comment: Judging from the reference, the solution is 2 or 3 pages long.  So it may not be reasonable to ask for it here.